# SSL Labs Key exchange < 100%, why? How do I make it?

Tags: https, security-certificate

I am in progress of trying to get maximum (or almost maximum) score on [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/)  my site:

I currently don't understand why it does not give me full [Key exchange score](https://github.com/ssllabs/research/wiki/SSL-Server-Rating-Guide#key-exchange).

Now, it looks like this:

[image: SSL Labs Key exchange < 100%]

In spite of, I have generated 4096 DHParameters file, and tried many other things, like buying new certificate of 4096 size.

So, my question for you will be:

SSL Labs Key exchange is less than 100%, why? And how do I make it full?

OS: GNU/Linux Debian 9.2 with Apache 2.4.

Comment: You got an A+ but that isn't good enough?     At some point you have to stop optimizing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the following file:

```
/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf
```

It was necessary to append these lines to ensure the highest grade of key exchange:

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd ECDHParameters Automatic
```

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Curves secp521r1:secp384r1
```

---

**UPDATE 2018-Apr-14**

I found out, that (at least Chrome, [read more on this topic here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/100991/82570)), decided to go for lower Key Exchange negotiation, namely P-256 (`prime256v1` in Apache2, though [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest) reports it like `secp256r1`) in spite of me having set the above curves.

So, I guess we should add P-256 to the list; please change the second line to:

```
SSLOpenSSLConfCmd Curves secp521r1:secp384r1:prime256v1
```